# MySql Auto Increment Failure to Increment Duplicate Position 0 Entry

Tags: mysql

We’re running the query:

```
INSERT INTO `macroSet` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Body Regions NEB-9377','2019-05-22 23:57:38','2019-05-22 23:57:38');
```

MYSQL is returning duplicate entry for key 0.

There is an entry for id position 0, but shouldn’t it increment with auto increment set and not try to insert another value at position key 0 ?

Also our increment value is 32 so technically it should set the increment to 32 after 0 correct?

Here is the table dump for our macro table.

```
CREATE TABLE `macroSet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subjectiveFolderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `objectiveFolderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessmentFolderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `planFolderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_name_macro_set` (`name`),
  KEY `fk_subjective_folder_id_macro_set` (`subjectiveFolderId`),
  KEY `fk_objective_folder_id_macro_set` (`objectiveFolderId`),
  KEY `fk_assessment_folder_id_macro_set` (`assessmentFolderId`),
  KEY `fk_plan_folder_id_macro_set` (`planFolderId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_assessment_folder_id_macro_set` FOREIGN KEY (`assessmentFolderId`) REFERENCES `folder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_objective_folder_id_macro_set` FOREIGN KEY (`objectiveFolderId`) REFERENCES `folder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_plan_folder_id_macro_set` FOREIGN KEY (`planFolderId`) REFERENCES `folder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subjective_folder_id_macro_set` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectiveFolderId`) REFERENCES `folder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any thoughts on what would cause this behavior would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd have to see the exact error to be sure, but it sounds more to me like perhaps your uniqueness key on `name` is being violated. _Also, try NULL instead of DEFAULT; maybe default is trying to force 0, where as auto increment knows what to do with null._

Comment: Take `id` out of your insert .. It's already auto incremented .. No need to be in the query itself ..

Comment: Not sure what issue do you have. I used your create statement (excluded FK definitions) and then executed a couple of your inserts with no issues. In these  inserts names were different (you have UQ on name). You sure that your error not related to unique_name_macro_set duplication?

Comment: in ours even if we have a entry for id 0 it says duplicate id 0 instead of auto incrementing when running the insert statement and we can't figure it out either. When we do it against our RDS cluster no issues, but when we do it against our kubernetes dev mysql which uses base mysql:5.7 docker image we have the issue we don't make any settings changes to the base image.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is 32 (AUTO_INCREMENT=32) theres no "default"

try :

```
INSERT INTO `macroSet` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (33, 'Body Regions NEB-9377','2019-05-22 23:57:38','2019-05-22 23:57:38');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `macroSet` (`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ('Body Regions NEB-9377','2019-05-22 23:57:38','2019-05-22 23:57:38');
```